# go get: Git settings ignored

Tags: go, gitlab-ci

I'm using Golang and GitLab CI, and I've got a GitLab CI configuration which works perfectly for 12 projects, but not for a 13th.

The problem I have is that I'm trying to `go get` some private repositories, which `go get` tries to run over HTTPS, which is turned off.

The solution, that works in the other repos, is this:

```
git config --global url."git@gitlab.my.site:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.my.site/"
```

However, in the runner for this one project, on the same GitLab, with the exact same config (except for the service name), this happens:

```
[...]
$ git config --global url."git@gitlab.my.site:".insteadOf "https://gitlab.my.site/"
$ cd ${APP_PATH}
$ go get
# cd .; git clone https://gitlab.my.site/group/project.git /go/src/gitlab.my.site/group/project
Cloning into '/go/src/gitlab.my.site/group/projects'...
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Why is it suddenly trying to clone over HTTPS? It happens in this one project only, consistently, but works in all the other ones. The only reason I can think about is that this one project uses a lot of different repos, rather than just one or two, but I have a hard time seing that this would be the actual issue.

How can I troubleshoot this?

Thanks.

Comment: Try to make manuallu `git clone -v ...` to check what's going on inside. If doesn't help, try to go deeper: `ssh -v git@gitlab.com`

Comment: Thanks, I'll start by running those two and get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, and it's silly, and of course, my fault. I hadn't added the deploy key to the projects, of course rejecting the clones.

To fix the problem, in GitLab, go to the repository and then "Settings" > "Repository" and fold out "Deploy keys". There, make sure that the key you're trying to clone with is available and enabled.